# how to remove the limit row condition from TMySQLrow in talend

Tags: talend

i am unable to remove the limit row condition from tMySQLrow  in talend. 
I tried to uncheck the checkbox but as soon as i close the window its getting rested to 100 (limit row).can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox gets selected again it might be a bug. But if you unselect it and it turns grey, then the 100 appers, it is just a non-used default value.